# Unreachable Browser Exception with Appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am automating android app using `appium`. Created driver using url.
Here i gave empty string for mobile web browser because i'm directly automating an app.

Here is the appium code,

```
public class Cal {
   private static AndroidDriver driver;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{
   File app = new File("C:\\Users\\Priya\\Desktop\\FitbaseApk\\Fitbase_01_21_2016_APK.apk");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Lenovo- A7000-a");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0"); 
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ionicframework.fitbase444706");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.ionicframework.fitbase444706.mainActivity"); 

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
}
```

Following is the error logs :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.49.0', revision: '365eeb4', time: '2016-01-13 18:33:29'
System info: host: 'QA1-PC', ip: '192.168.0.82', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:161)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:170)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:82)
at FitbaseApp.Cal.main(Cal.java:37)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
Build info: version: '2.49.0', revision: '365eeb4', time: '2016-01-13 18:33:29'
System info: host: 'QA1-PC', ip: '192.168.0.82', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:67)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is at .

> HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1]
>   failed:

Try restarting appijum server, if issue persists try changing the port number in server and in code[image]

Comment: Thanks you Karthick23 for replying. I got solution for this. The problem occurs because for appium takes relatively long time to start. You can see it at the end i gave "driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);". I removed it, now it's working fine..

Comment: @Lakshmi Priya thats good..if you feel if you have learnt somethng useful from my answer kindly upvote it.. thanks in advance

Comment: ok. I beleive it will get added once you gain your reputation

Comment: Hi Karthik23, Script is running successfully on device but after that it's showing SessionNotCreatedException exception on eclipse console. can u plz help me?

Comment: If scripts are done successfully hope your task is done..it might be intermittent issue..if its persists try reverting back to port 4723 or anyother port and try..if still occurs paste ur logs

Comment: Hi Karthik, Now the script i snot at all running, it's showing session not created error even if i run server correctly and in logs it's showing this issue "> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched"

Comment: This is intermittent. It occurs bcos both uiautomator and appium server use same session id..i would recommend u to do a one time restart of ur pc and session cached woukd be flushed off

Comment: I found solution Karthik, that's b/c of Api level of android. I installed api's for level 21 now it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

I got solution for this. The problem occurs because for appium takes relatively long time to start. You can see it at the end i gave "driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);". Here i decreased the time, now it's working fine..

Answer (score 1):

With the above code, you shouldn't put a fixed Thread.Sleep at all, because you never know how long appium is gonna take to start. Best way is to start appium programatically and then monitor http://localhost:4723, this is where appium always runs. You need to keep on sending request to this url and and wait until you get response from this url, once you get response thats where you should initialise the driver, something like, if you understand this I'll post whole code, httpClientWrap is my library.

```
public static boolean waitForAppiumServer()
    {
        boolean flag = false;

        for(int i=0; i<=20; i++)
        {       
            String status = httpClientWrap.sendGetRequest("http://localhost:4723/wd/status");

            if(!status.isEmpty())
            {
                logger.info("appium service has been launched successfully. ");

                flag = true;
                break;
            }

            logger.info("appium service has not been launched, waiting to get started .... attempt: "+i);

            try {Thread.sleep(3000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }

        return flag;
    }
```